# Replace div background-image with a blob - jQuery / CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blob

I am trying to update a background image with a base64 BLOB taken from a database.

**HTML:**

```
<div valign="bottom" class="profile-photo card-header color-white no-border"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var profilePhoto = data.profilePhoto;

$(".profile-photo").css("background-image","url(data:image/png;base64," + profilePhoto + ")");
```

`profilePhoto` definitely contains the binary data, verifed by a `console.log()`, but for whatever reason this is not working!

Comment: Does it work you you manually paste the blob in the jQuery code?

Comment: No, it works if I just use a url instead of a blob, pasted or otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the extra colon sign `:` from the first parameter `background-image` passed to `css()` function :

```
$(".profile-photo").css("background-image","url(data:image/png;base64," + profilePhoto + ")");
```

Instead of :

```
$(".profile-photo").css("background-image:","url(data:image/png;base64," + profilePhoto + ")");
_________________________________________^
```

**NOTE :** Try to encode your string first using `btoa()` :

```
var profilePhoto = btoa(data.profilePhoto);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: apologies, that was left over from a previous attempt at getting it to work, neither of the above seem to work.

Comment: Ok please share with us the output of `console.log("url(data:image/png;base64," + profilePhoto + ")");`...

Comment: /9j/4QOca ... doesn't look like base64 encoded data

Comment: Encode the image data using base64 then paste the string in your jQuery expression

Comment: you are right, looks like a random online "png to base64" encoder did something weird! tried again with a proper base64 image and it works as expected, thank you

Answer (score 0):

if your profilePhoto variable getting correct value. then only one mistake in your code. 1st you need to remove colon (:) after the background-image. and also removing the white space in profilePhoto variable left and right side.like below code.

```
$(".profile-photo").css("background-image","url(data:image/png;base64,"+profilePhoto+")");
```